# Getting Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, json

Following is my code : 
I am sending the jSON object from one activity to another Activity.

```
// In LoginActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,EmpLoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

intent.putExtra("data",jsonObject.toString());
```

In EmpLoginActivty.java

```
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("data"));
            tv1.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            tv2.setText(jsonObject.getString("type"));
            tv3.setText(jsonObject.getString("hours"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Error :**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.krish.emp/com.example.krish.emp.EmpLoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Debug code, looks like jsonObject.toString is returning Null.

Comment: Try calling `startActivity` _after_ you call `intent.putExtra`

Comment: Sorry !! Just a silly mistake.
Thank you @EJK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully populate the Intent before you pass it to `startActivity`.

So change this:

```
startActivity(intent);
intent.putExtra("data",jsonObject.toString());
```

to this:

```
intent.putExtra("data",jsonObject.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```